# Getting OAuth Token from a google service

Tags: python, oauth, google-oauth

I am trying to get all the contacts of the current user via gmail.

I registered domain and got those keys here: `https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains`

I have a local server running and responding to oauth_callback_url at

```
`127.0.0.1:8000/google/oauth/cb/`
```

I try the following code then in the shell to see if I am getting a token and a secret,
following is the code I tried, which is followed by the output which I have received:

```
import oauth2 as oauth, requests

consumer = oauth.Consumer(my_consumer_key, my_consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = 'http://%s/google/oauth/cb/' % (request.META.get('HTTP_HOST'))
resp, content = client.request("%s?%s" % (GOOGLE_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL), method="GET")
```

### Output

```
In [21]: content
Out[21]: 'parameter_absent\noauth_parameters_absent:scope\n\n'

In [22]: resp
Out[22]: 
{'-content-encoding': 'gzip',
 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0',
 'content-length': '48',
 'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
 'date': 'Mon, 22 Jul 2013 11:09:53 GMT',
 'expires': 'Mon, 22 Jul 2013 11:09:53 GMT',
 'server': 'GSE',
 'status': '400',
 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block'}
```

Please let me know, what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

As was already visible in the output, scope params were missing, so adding scope urls helped.

For contat the scope url is - https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/